# Extending a diffeomorphism outside a compact set

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I believe that the following statement is true:

*Let $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open sets, $K\subset U$ compact, and $\gamma:U\to V$ a diffeomorphism. Then there is a diffeomorphism $\Gamma:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Gamma|_K=\gamma|_K$.*

However, I do not know how to prove it in a few lines, and I do not know a reference for it. If someone told me a resource where the statement is proved, it would be really helpful.

Of course, if the statement is actually wrong, then it would be even more helpful if someone told me.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: As shown below, the statement is not true as stated above. However, the special case of contractible (or say, just simply connected) $K$ ist also of interest to me. What can we say then?**

Comment: My answer below aside, the statement may be true if you require $K$ to be not only compact but also contractible. Is that sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: It might be sufficient. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You may want to ask it as a separate question. At the present I cannot come up with a good proof that works in all dimensions. In 1D the result is trivial. In 2D you can find a subset $U'$ of $U$ and a subset $V'$ of $V$ such that $U' \supset K$ and is contractible, with $\gamma$ a diffeo between $U'$ and $V'$. Then you apply Riemann mapping to $U'$ and $V'$ to get them to be open balls, and then gluing on the outside is not too hard. For 3D however it is not true that contractible is homeo to ball. So I am not so sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated it is false.

Let 
$$ U = (-1,0) \cup (10,11) \subset \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$ V = (1,2) \cup (15,16) \subset \mathbb{R} $$
Take 
$$ K = \{ -2/3, -1/3 , 10.5\} $$

Let $\gamma$ be the map 
$$ \gamma(x) = \begin{cases}
x + 16 & x \in (-1,0) \\
x - 9 & x \in (10,11)\end{cases} $$
which is clearly a diffeomorphism of $U$ and $V$.

But $\gamma|_{K}$ is not order preserving, so cannot equal the restriction of a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

---

For a connected example: let $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $U = V = \{r \in (1/2,2) \}$. Let $K = \{r \in [3/4,4/3]\}$. Let $\gamma$ be the inversion around the unit sphere: $(r,\theta) \mapsto (1/r,\theta)$. This is a diffeomorphism of $U$ to $V$. And also an automorphism of $K$. But any diffeomorphism extension of $\gamma|_K$ need to give a diffeomorphism betweeh the $B(3/4)$ and $\overline{B(4/3)}^C$ which is not possible since the two are not even homeomorphic.