# Find diffeomorphism maps a subset of the domain to a convex set

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and bounded and $K\subset U$ be a compact set. By the Riemann mapping theorem, I can find a diffeomorphism $Φ:U \to B:= {|x| < 1}$. However, can I choose $\Phi$ such that $\Phi(K)$ is convex?

---

This question is basically a follow up to [Extending a diffeomorphism onto a larger set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232513/). Here I had hoped that I could first construct a diffeomorphism $\Psi: K^\circ \to B$ and then extend it to $U$, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Careful: Riemann's mapping Theorem only applies in dimension $2$ (*i.e* in $\mathbb{C}$), and for $U$ non-empty and simply connected.

Comment: In addition: you should require for $K$ to be simply-connected, otherwise its image by a diffeomorphism could not be simply-connected and hence cannot be convex (consider an annulus).